# Difference in values after doing operations on elements in Int16Array and Array.Prototype.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays

When doing the same operations on the elements of the two different types of array, i get different outputs. I guess there are some underlying problem i am not aware of.

```
const mData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let data1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(mData.data);
    var data = Int16Array.from(mData.data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i] = data[i] * 2 - 255;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
      data1[i] = data1[i] * 2 - 255;
    }

    
    data1.sort();
    data.sort();
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data);
```

The arrays have been sorted in order to show the changes. As can be seen, the values are not the same.
Output picture

Comment: Please create fiddle with sample data so that we can se problem in [mre]

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) with example data, rather than (or in addition to) a fiddle. cc @ikiK

Comment: Please [edit] you question and either embed the image by prepending an exclamation-mark, e.g. `![array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJSQb.png)` or (better) post the array from console-output as plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the sort method did not do a numerical sort, which made it seem like the values were not the same in the two arrays.